# Unable to add product into cart from third party CURL

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart, curl

I have created custom controller in which I've written custom add to cart action and shared controller URL with 3rd party website. That website is calling my controller using CURL and on success, 3rd party website is redirecting to my cart page. But product is not be able to add into cart.

If I am calling my controller from browser, product will be added into cart successfully.

Can you please help me out.

Thank you in advance.

Regards,
Kunjesh

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell exactly as there are lots of reasons why the endpoint might not work.

The cart is session based, the browser keeps a session open with the server by using cookies, how is the 3rd party keeping the session with the server?

Also when the browsers calls the add to cart controller, it sends a form key to avoid CSRF attacks https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery which is technically the same as what you are doing, calling the endpoint from outside the browser.